Applying for Mphil in Ireland without transcripts due to war
I would like to know what the likelihood of being accepted into Trinity College Dublin Mphil in International Peace Studies if I don't have my official transcripts due the war in my country Sudan. There is no way to receive the transcripts because my university has been literally burnt down. However, I have my general certificate which testifies that I graduated with a Second class honours division one. The website only mentions getting a 2.1 from a university in dublin or equivalent. I am also sitting for my CPE english exam to attach to my application.
So honestly speaking, will I be able to get in. I spoke with my dean and she said she could write them a letter to explain my circumstances. Would that help?
Thank you very much.

You have to ask them.

(more) You need to contact them for what alternatives there might be and what you need to do to find acceptance. No one here can speak for them. Support letters from professors are probably needed.

Closing this for now -- since you're only asking about one school, you need to ask that school. If you like, you could rewrite the question along the lines of "how does/should this work in this part of the world generally" (and we could reopen it in that form) -- but this may or may not be useful to you, since there is no guarantee that your specific program will handle things in a usual or reasonable way.
